# Finding next number in column preceded by a letter

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have create a form for some people to add/modify records in an access table. What I need to do is write a function that automatically finds the next available number from a column when the user is adding a new record.

The problem I am having is that the numbers in the column I need to increment are preceded by either an R or a W so I can't just use a DMax function. I am writing an input box to ask for the first character and then I need it to search for the greatest number and give them the next available.

For example the column has:

```
R1000
R1001
W1000
R1002
W1001
W1002
R1003
```

And when the user specifies "R" I need it to return "1004" as the next available.

EDIT: So, this may then need to be moved to different category as I have a code that works. I just don't know if this is the most efficient:

```
Dim MaxValue As Integer
Dim db As dao.Database
Dim rs As dao.Recordset

Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT GlobalAcct FROM TestTable")

rs.MoveLast
rs.MoveFirst

MaxValue = 0

Do While Not rs.EOF
    If MaxValue = 0 Or CInt(Right(rs!GlobalAcct, 4)) > MaxValue Then
        MaxValue = CInt(Right(rs!GlobalAcct, 4))
    End If

    rs.MoveNext
Loop

MaxValue = MaxValue + 1
Debug.Print MaxValue
```

Comment: My only thought process has been to loop through every item depending on the first character, store the Right(Value, 4) in a variable, check if it is greater than the next row, if not -pass, if so - update variable and do that for every row but it seems very redundant.

Comment: A better design and much simpler process would be to use two separate fields instead of a single field. One to store the text portion and the other to store the number. You can then simply use dmax whenever you need the next number. Anywhere in the app that you need to display the entire value, you can simply concatenate the two fields. It is always simpler to join things together than to parse them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a function that will return a long representing the largest account that begins with whatever letter you pass in.

```
Public Function GetLastAccount(ByVal sPrefix As String) As Long

    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim aSql(1 To 4)  As String

    aSql(1) = "SELECT TOP 1 Val(Right(GlobalAcct,Len(GlobalAcct)-1)) As NumAct"
    aSql(2) = "FROM TestTable"
    aSql(3) = "WHERE Left(GlobalAcct,1)='" & sPrefix & "'"
    aSql(4) = "ORDER BY GlobalAcct DESC"

    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    rs.Open Join(aSql, Space(1)), Application.CurrentProject.Connection

    GetLastAccount = rs.Fields("NumAct").Value

End Function
```

In use:

```
?getlastaccount("R")
 1003 
?getlastaccount("w")
 1002
```

Then you can add 1 to it or whatever you want to do.

The SQL statement is a `SELECT TOP 1` with an `ORDER BY DESC` - that's how you get the maximum value and you don't have to return or navigate through a huge recordset.

The `Val` and `Right` functions are used to isolate the numeric part of the account. There's a lot of assumptions, including that the accounts start with a single character that you want to ignore, the rest of the characters are numeric, and you will never pass in a character where at least one record is returned. But you can work out those details.